# Check if document contains any string from array and replace it

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to check the document for any string in a given array and replace it with something `<em>matched string</em>`.

I tried just looping through the array and replacing any match from that, but with my long array that locks up the document for a good amount of time.

Example:

```
array.forEach(function(v) {
               console.log(v);
               var html = '<em>' + v + '</em>';
               var re = new RegExp(v, "gi");
               document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, html)
           })
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Please don't ever do anything like replacing `document.body.innerHTML`. There's many implications you aren't considering. You'll need to recursively traverse throughout the whole document and look for text nodes. If the text node contains the value you're trying to match, you need to replace it with an `<em>` containing that text

Comment: Hopefully `v` is not in an attribute or tag name.

Comment: Oooh. I didn't even think of that. Crap. It likely wouldn't be but I don't like leaving things open to chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the under-utilized **TreeWalker** DOM API, as follows:

```
var walk = document.createTreeWalker(document, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false),
    n;

while(n = walk.nextNode()) {
    n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.replace(/foo/g, 'bar');
}
```

The `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` tells TreeWalker you only are interested in text nodes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker for more information.

But you want to replace the text with a more complex DOM structure, involving the `em` element, so we have to do a bit more work:

```
function emphasize(regexp) {
    var walk = document.createTreeWalker(document, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false),
        n, span;

    while (n = walk.nextNode()) {
        newVal = n.nodeValue.replace(regexp, function(match) { 
            return "<em>" + match + "</em>";
        });

        if (newVal !== n.nodeValue) {
            span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = newVal;
            n.parentNode.replaceChild(span, n);
        }
    }
}
```

It could be Nodewalker will not be too happy about having its current node being replaced out from under it. That would require a bit of testing and possible tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-[\/{}*+?.\\\]^$]/g, "\\$&");
}

var code = document.body.innerHTML;
array.forEach(function(v) {
  code = code.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(v)), "g"), "<em>"+v+"</em>")
}
document.body.innerHTML = code;
```

I am avoiding multiple assignments to innerHTML to avoid unnecessary reflows (performance)

Comment: You don't need to escape all those things in your `escapeRegExp` regexp. Just escape backslash and `]`. Dash needs no escaping if it's the first character in the character set. So it will work just fine to do `/[-[/{}*+?.\\\]^$]/`. Aside from that, in general this a horrible idea, which has a high probability of destroying the document beyond recognition.